# draw html table header

Tags: asp.net, html, css, html-table

i have table structures like this

```
 <table class="dgrid" rules="all" id="Gridview2" style="border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">HEADER 1</th>
            <th scope="col">HEADER 2</th>
            <th scope="col">HEADER 3</th>
            <th scope="col">HEADER 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DATA 1</td>
            <td>DATA 2</td>
            <td>DATA 3</td>
            <td>DATA 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

based on this structures, i want to draw the header table with color. i've do this CSS but nothing happened

```
<style>
    .dgrid th scope {
        color: #18bc9c;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the attribute selector `[attribute="value"]`

```css
.dgrid th[scope="col"] {
  color: #18bc9c;
}
```

```html
<table class="dgrid" rules="all" id="Gridview2" style="border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">HEADER 1</th>
      <th scope="col">HEADER 2</th>
      <th scope="col">HEADER 3</th>
      <th scope="col">HEADER 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DATA 1</td>
      <td>DATA 2</td>
      <td>DATA 3</td>
      <td>DATA 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: oh man thanks, it works now.. i doesn't think CSS3 is have selectors. thanks man!